# Trying to share zustand with vite module federation

Tags: reactjs, vite, zustand

I have two apps one has the zustand store with

```
export const useUser = create<UserSlice>((set) => ({
    user: user,
    setUser: (user: User) => {
        set(() => ({
            user: user,
        }));
    },
    randomUsername: (username: string) =>
        set(
            produce((state) => {
                state.user.username = username;
            })
        ),
    changeLanguage: (lang: string) =>
        set(
            produce((state) => {
                state.user.language = lang;
            })
        ),
    resetUser: () => {
        set(initialState);
    },
}));
```

This is the config that is exposing it

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        federation({
            name: 'core',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            exposes: {
                './Button': './src/components/Button.tsx',
                './useUser': './src/stores/Store.ts',
            },
            shared: ['react', 'react-dom', 'zustand', 'immer'],
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8001,
    },
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: 'esnext',
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
});
```

In my host I have

```
federation({
            name: 'host',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            remotes: {
                core: 'http://localhost:8001/dist/assets/remoteEntry.js',
            },
            exposes: {},
            shared: ['react', 'react-dom'],
        }),
```

When trying to use the useUser hook im getting

```
caught TypeError: create is not a function
```

for the useUser = create()
I dont understand why this is happening, and how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I just have found that if you switch from

```
import { create } from "zustand";
```

to

```
import create from "zustand";
```

it works but I have found other errors